# I updated UEFI firmware and now can't even boot into Windows RE from a USB

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios, updates

My PC came prebuilt from a vendor when I bought it 2-3 years ago with UEFI firmware version 1823 on it, and two days ago I updated the UEFI firmware version to 3122 and this is what happened:

1. I downloaded UEFI firmware version 3211 for my motherboard from the official ASUS support web site
2. I formatted a USB to GPT and FAT32 using Rufus, extracted the ZIP file containing the `.CAP` file inside the USB using 7zip, and used the renaming tool on the `.CAP` file
3. I deleted the ZIP file and renaming tool, leaving only the `.CAP` file in the USB, and properly ejected the USB
4. I went into the UEFI firmware and navigated to EZ Flash 3 utility, where I found my USB and `.CAP` file, and proceeded to update my UEFI firmware.

   1. When it was finished, it rebooted and everything went fine (or so I thought).
   2. I got prompted to press <kbd>F1</kbd> by an *American Megatrends* screen to head over to the UEFI firmware settings
   3. I shut down the computer, unplugged the power chord, and held the power button to discharge, then I carefully removed the CMOS battery for 5+ minutes and put it back in
   4. When I booted back into the UEFI firmware, I selected *Load Optimized defaults*, changed the date/time and boot options, and pressed <kbd>F10</kbd>
5. The PC restarted, went through POST to a Windows logo with the spinning dots on the bottom, and after ~3s the dots stopped spinning and the PC froze up
6. I downloaded Windows RE onto a USB, and the same problem occurs.

   - I have tried to make the USB with Windows Media Creation Tool and with Rufus using the ISO *(when using Rufus I tried both with GPT(NTFS) and with MBR(NTFS))*, and nothing has worked
7. To try and revert what I did, I downloaded UEFI firmware version 1823 [the original UEFI firmware version], but when I go into EZ flash 3 and locate the `.CAP` file, I get prompted with *File is not a proper UEFI firmware*
8. I have tried:

   - booting into an Ubuntu and Manjaro LiveUSB, both allowing me to select the OS in Grub, but then gets stuck after GRUB
   - running Memtest86 from a USB for 3-4 hours and it went through all four passes without errors

---

After 2 days of trying just about any combination of boot order and boot settings, I managed to get the Windows RE USB to boot, getting prompted with the *Select you language* screen; however, before I can open a terminal or select anything, the PC freezes up and I´m forced to reboot.

- **Setup when testing for the past two days:**

  - 1 Ram stick in the "A2" position on the MB.
  - I plugged out all other peripherals except for my keyboard and Display Port cable for my monitor.
  - I only have 1 harddrive connected which is the M.2 SSD.
  - And lastly My GPU is connected as I think my CPU doesnt have integrated graphics on it.
- **Specs:**

  - Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B450M-A
  - GPU: ASUS DUAL-RX580-O4G
  - CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (3.6GHz,65W,L3:32M,6C,B0)
  - RAM: GoodRAM GX2400 DDR4 8GB DIMM
- **Screenshots:** [image: Screenshot1] [image: Screenshot2] [image: Screenshot3]

Comment: It’s normal to be unable to downgrade your firmware

Comment: Is secure boot enabled? Is your system set to use CSM (compatibility support module) or UEFI mode?

Comment: @Mokubai Secure boot is disabled, and I´ve tried every combination I can think of with CSM. I have disabled it with the same results.

I have it enabled right now, as booting the USB stick in legacy mode with fast boot off was what got me the furthest into "language select" before it froze again.

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to downgrade the version to BIOS version.3205 and 2807. But both of them gave me the same results as the newest one 3211.

Comment: Was Windows installed in Legacy Mode or UEFI mode?

Comment: @Ramhound I´m pretty sure it got installed in UEFI mode. But I honestly stopped trying to boot into the OS on my harddrive when I noticed that I couldnt even boot on a recovery USB.

But I have the option to choose both "Windows boot manager (M.2 WDC WDS240G2G0B-00EPW0)" and just the harddrive if that clarifys anything.

Comment: A modern Windows system should expect CSM disabled and secure boot enabled, Linux is unreliable at best to determine what settings are required.

Comment: @Mokubai I just now tried to enable secure boot + disable CSM. And it gets stuck on "Preparing Automatic Repair" with then dots spinning in a wheel at first, but the freezing.

Same result with secure boot disabled + CSM disabled

Comment: > and then changed the date/time + booting options. 

Did the "booting options" include the setting for AHCI mode?

Comment: So that definitely suggests that in that state your system disk is found and bootable with secure boot enabled and csm disabled. I'd check what memory slot is supposed to be used for a single stick in your motherboard manual, often it is B2. It could be your memory controller locking up during windows kernel init...

Comment: I would check the memory timings look sane and are set up right, A2 seems to be the correct slot, but I'd be tempted to put another stick in B2.

Comment: @r2d3 I have looked through everything in my BIOS except for OC and CPU tuning. And I have the following setting:
SATA Configuration -> SATA Mode Selection -> AHCI/RAID

Comment: @Mokubai I have tested both of my ram sticks individually in both A2 and B2 with no success. After that I just left one of them in the A2 slot as I read about it quickly in the manual while continuing testing.

Also I just now after reading your comment left the settings to be secure boot + disabled CSM with the RAM in B2 slot. Again it gets stuck on "Preparing automatic repair"

Comment: @Mokubai I´m not that proficient with this kind of stuff ^^ So idk how to check or know what a "sane" memory timing looks like.

But I ran memory speed test on Memtest86 just now, heres the results: https://imgur.com/a/0rMhXam

Comment: Piet, important settings may only be visible when you switch your motherboard to "extended" mode. What are the other SATA mode labeled, by the way?

Comment: It being stuck on “Preparing Automatic Repair" means your installation is hosed

Comment: Your memory is in an XMP mode for memtest, can you at least disable that and recheck? Memtest may not be doing the same setup as Windows/Linux kernels so I'd be trying to back off on that side first. That you get "Preparing automatic repair" tells us that those are the correct settings to make your system bootable, but something is causing it to fail, hence I was looking around other setting that much have changed when you reset your CMOS and reset to defaults.

Comment: @r2d3 The BIOS settings are in "Advanced mode" but there´s nothing about AHCI under the boot tab atleast, but I couldnt find it anywhere else than here: https://imgur.com/a/8FLfRQK

Comment: @Mokubai I saw this on a few forums, but after an hour of searching I never found anything in the BIOS settings about XMP or "extreme memory profiles."

Every setting that has to do with CPU or Memory is either on default but also most likely on auto. But I dont know what 90% of them are.

Comment: @PietFossberg _(BIOS is not the same as UEFI, you have UEFI)_ Due to the system freezes, you have a hardware issue somewhere - run the built-in UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics, accessible either from within the UEFI firmware or from the UEFI boot options page _(they will initially run a short test on all components, and if that doesn't find anything, run the long test - short will take >1hr, long will take several hrs)_. Short of it being a hardware issue, did you verify the hash of the UEFI firmware update after downloading? Have you tried redownloading and re-flashing the current version?

Comment: @JW0914 Sorry if my terminology is off ^^
"built-in UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics" I can´t find it in the UEFI firmware, and all it says on the ASUS logo when booting up is how to get into the UEFI firmware. Except for that I just know how to bring up the boot meny with (F8). 
I do however have "Launch EFI shell from USB drives", but I dont know exactly how that works, or how i get it on a USB drive.
I didn´t verify the download no, but I did re-flash it after I downgraded to version.2807 and went back to 3211.

Comment: @PietFossberg All motherboards have built-in diagnostics for the motherboard and attached hardware components, and normally the diagnostics are able to be selected from within the BIOS/UEFI firmware or from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot options screen _(it's not the EFI shell, as that's something different)_. If the motherboard's manual doesn't list how to access the built-in hardware diagnostics, you may want to email ASUS and/or use a search engine of choice to search for your motherboard's model number and built-in diagnostics

Comment: @PietFossberg _Cont'd..._ An easy way to determine if it's a hardware component is to fully disconnect every component except one RAM DIMM _(ensure the PSU is fully disconnected from power prior to)_. All motherboards support basic graphics without the use of a discrete [add-on] GPU _(usually via VGA)_, so what I would try is once everything is fully disconnected, boot the WinPE/WinRE USB and see if it freezes up; if it doesn't, shut it back down, remove power, install the M.2, and boot back to WinRE, etc.

Comment: @Mokubai I fixed it, PC works fine now. No hardware has been harmed or anything!
The issue turned out to be XMP. BUT it wasn´t that simple. First off XMP is called "D.O.C.P" on AMD setups. Which noone talks about anywere so I had no clue that it was staring me right in the face. Secondly it was on DISABLED both before and after I flashed my BIOS I have photos of it being disabled. But apparently it was enabled eventhough the BIOS/UEFI says otherwise. When I chose "profile 1" and turned XMP on the PC booted just fine afterwards!
I really do appreciate the fast responses and ideas, THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad you found the final solution to bring everything back to life, it is somewhat annoying that they are named one way in every place except AMD systems though. Could be that as you say it was partially enabled and when the OS started up it went to reconfigure the memory and ended up with invalid settings. Sadly fault-finding over the Internet is a tricky process at best... in a day or so you should be able to "accept" your answer to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, PC works fine now. No hardware has been harmed or anything.

The issue turned out to be XMP. BUT it wasn´t that simple. First off XMP is called "D.O.C.P" on AMD setups. Which noone talks about anywere so I had no clue that it was staring me right in the face. Secondly it was on DISABLED both before and after I flashed my BIOS I have photos of it being disabled. But apparently it was enabled eventhough the BIOS/UEFI says otherwise. When I chose "profile 1" and turned XMP on the PC booted just fine afterwards.

Comment: If you ever do a UEFI update again, make a backup of the BIOS/UEFI settings to a USB stick - it is then easy to get the settings back. And if you're using BitLocker on the OS drive, suspend that before doing the update.